# how to export visual studio generated code coverage results to sonarQube dashboard using jenkins

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, jenkins, sonarqube

I am working on C# project and trying to export code coverage results on visual studio to sonarqube via jenkins. Researched online for almost a day but there is no detailed explanation on how does it work or which is the right plugin to use. Tried using OpenCover, MS Build and SonarLint but they didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at

- [Code Coverage Results Import (C#, VB.NET)](http://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6389770)
- [Jenkins section of in the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/From+Jenkins)
- [Analyzing with SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins)

To accomplish this I'm using:

1. SonarQube (version 5.6.1)
2. [Analyzing with SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins)(latest version)
3. [OpenCover](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover) (latest version)
4. [nUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) (2.6.3)
5. Visual Studio 2015 (Update 3)
6. MSBuild 14 (installed by VS2015)